# shading under time-series curve ggplot2 r

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have this code for the purpose of making a figure

```
milliseconds <- c(0,50,100,150,200,250,300)
force <- c(20,75,120,260,400,500,600)
data <- data.frame(miliseconds,force)
```

I need to shade 0 to 50 milliseconds under the curve.

So far I have

```
RFD <-ggplot(data = data, mapping = aes(x = miliseconds, y = force)) +
  geom_line(color="black", size=2) +
  geom_area(mapping = aes(x = ifelse(x>0 & x<50 , x, 0)),
        geom_params = list(fill = "red", alpha = 0.5)) +
  scale_y_continuous(limits = c(0, max(data$force)))
  geom_point(size=4, color="black") +
  theme_classic() +
  ggtitle("Rate of Force Developement")


RFD +scale_x_continuous(name = "Milliseconds",
                        breaks = seq(0, 300, 50),
                        limits=c(0, 300)) +
  scale_y_continuous(name = "Force")
```

##########

but Im getting an error that I cant ggproto object together.
any suggestions?

Comment: `scale_y_continuous(limits = c(0, max(RFD$force)))` if RFD is the plot object, presumably you want to refer to `data$force` for the data?

Comment: Typo in milliseconds (sometimes one l, sometimes two)

Comment: Missing + at end of scale_y_continuous before geom_point

Comment: In your ifelse, I think you mean the "x"s to be "milliseconds"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After removing typos, I think the main problem is that there are no data within the limits ( `> 0 & < 50`) you set.

But you also should apply this filter to `data` in `geom_area` with the same mapping as in `ggplot`. I have used slightly different filters for getting at least some data. If you put `fill` and `alpha` just outside of the aesthetics it will work.

You do not have to use `df$force` in `scale_y_continuous`.

PS:

- I have removed the legend and used `linewidth` instead of `size` in `geom_line`.
- the error message comes from the missing `+`
- there is no `geom_params`

```r
library(tidyverse)

milliseconds <- c(0,50,100,150,200,250,300)
force <- c(20,75,120,260,400,500,600)
df <- data.frame(milliseconds,force)

RFD <- ggplot(data = df, mapping = aes(x = milliseconds, y = force)) +
  geom_line(color="black", linewidth=2) +
  geom_area(data = df |> filter(milliseconds > 0 & milliseconds < 150),
            mapping = aes(x = milliseconds, y = force), 
            fill = 'red', alpha = .5) +
  scale_y_continuous(name = 'Force', limits = c(0, max(force))) +
  scale_x_continuous(name = "Milliseconds",
                     breaks = seq(0, 300, 50),
                     limits=c(0, 300)) +
  geom_point(size=4, color="black") +
    theme_classic() + theme(legend.position = 'none') +
    ggtitle("Rate of Force Developement")

RFD
```

[image]

Comment: I think you need to change the filter to `filter(milliseconds >= 0 & milliseconds <= 50)` if you want to shade the area between 0 and 50 as requested by the OP. Also, it would look better if you moved the geom_area to be drawn before the geom_line.

Comment: @`Allen Cameron` you are right, of course. I just wanted to get some area, didn't pay attention to what was wanted. Do you mind leaving it as it is?

Comment: yes absolutely.  That was exactly what I was looking for. Had a very difficult time finding something similar